# What's the best practice to return from a function which returns Task<CustomType>, if no data found?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, webapi, clean-architecture

I have the following code, my question is, when no data found, what's the best practice to return?
Currently I am returning null, but is there any better suggestable approach, like throw exception or error?Any guidance will be appretiated.
This is is my Repository method of an web api get endpoint.

```
public async Task<CustomerProfileDto> Handle(GetCustomerProfileQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var query = from Customer in _context.Customers
                            .Include("SystemCustomers")
                            .Include("SystemCustomers.SystemCustomerCreditors")
                            .Include("SystemCustomers.SystemCustomerCreditors.Creditor")
                            .Include("SystemCustomers.SystemRole")
                            .Include("SystemCustomers.SystemRole.System")
                    join SystemCustomer in _context.SystemCustomers on Customer.Id equals SystemCustomer.CustomerId
                    join SystemRoles in _context.SystemRoles on SystemCustomer.SystemRoleId equals SystemRoles.Id
                    join Systems in _context.Systems on SystemRoles.SystemId equals Systems.Id
                    join SystemCustomerCreditor in _context.SystemCustomerCreditors on SystemCustomer.Id equals SystemCustomerCreditor.SystemCustomerId
                    join Creditor in _context.Creditors on SystemCustomerCreditor.CreditorId equals Creditor.Id
                    where Customer.Email == request.Email &&
                         Systems.Code == request.SystemCode &&
                         SystemCustomer.SystemRole.Id == _context.SystemCustomers.Where(au => au.CustomerId == SystemCustomer.CustomerId)
                         .OrderByDescending(au => au.SystemRole.RoleType.Priority)
                         .FirstOrDefault().SystemRole.Id &&
                         (request.ExternalReference == null || Customer.ExternalReference == request.ExternalReference)
                    select new
                    {
                        CustomerData = Customer,
                        Creditorconfig = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthenticationConfiguration>(Creditor.AuthenticationConfigJObjectData)
                    };
        if (query.Any())
        {
            ///TO-DO: Incorporate CancellationToken if  possible 
            var CustomerData = query.FirstOrDefault().CustomerData;
            var result = _mapper.Map<CustomerProfileDto>(CustomerData);
            var clientaddress = query.FirstOrDefault().Creditorconfig.Clientaddresses.ToList();
            if (clientaddress.Any())
            {
                var addressDetails = new IPAdressDetails { Currentaddress = request.address, Clientaddresses = clientaddress };
                result.IsIPWhitelisted = _addressValidator.IsAddressWhitelisted(addressDetails);
            }    
            return result;
        }
        //whats the best alternative of sending null here?
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Returning `null` is fine, but you should cache `query.FirstOrDefault()` and check that for null, instead of calling `.Any()`

Comment: Questions asking for *best practices* are opinion-based, and therefore off-topic here. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296542/62576. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: `query.Any()`, `query.FirstOrDefault()`, `query.FirstOrDefault()`: are you sure that you are not issuing three consecutive requests to the database? Not only this would be inefficient, but it would be also possible to get different results from each request, invalidating the logic of the (arguably not aptly named) `Handle` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only *"best"* practice that I can give you is not to use exceptions for valid aplication paths.

Throwing exception should only be used for exceptional cases, not for normal application flows. If you know a path can be reached an it  an be handled then it is not exceptional anymore.

About returning null, that is perfectly valid if there is only one reason for not returning a valid `CustomerProfileDto`, i.e. when there is no object that satisfies the request.

If there are more reason for failing to fullfill the request (i.e an API endpoint that can return NotFound or BadRequest or other values depending on the request and/or the values in the data source) then a `OperationResult` pattern may be more appropiate.

The [`OperationResult`](https://www.google.com/search?q=operation+result+pattern) is a a concept to wrap the response in an object that can be interrogated if the operation was successful or not, to get the value if it was correct, or to get the error messages or error codes if it was not successful.

An implementation of the pattern that I have actually used in production (you can improve it to fit your needs) is the following:

```cs
public class Result
{
    private const string EmptyErrorsMessage = "errors cannot be empty";

    public bool Success { get; }

    public ResultType Type { get; }

    public List<string> Errors { get; } = new();

    protected Result(bool success, ResultType type, params string[] errors)
    {
        Success = success;
        Type = type;
        Errors.AddRange(errors);
    }

    public static Result Successful() => new(true, ResultType.Successful);

    public static Result Failed(params string[] errors) => new(false, ResultType.Failed, ValidateErrors(errors));

    public static Result NotFound(params string[] errors) => new(false, ResultType.NotFound, ValidateErrors(errors));

    protected static string[] ValidateErrors(string[] errors) =>
        errors switch
        {
            null => throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(errors)),
            { Length: 0 } => throw new ArgumentException(EmptyErrorsMessage, nameof(errors)),
            _ => errors
        };
}

public class Result<T> : Result
{
    private const string NoValueOnFailedOperationMessage = "There is no value on a failed operation";

    private readonly T _value;

    public T Value =>
        Success
            ? _value
            : throw new InvalidOperationException(NoValueOnFailedOperationMessage);

    private Result(bool success, ResultType type, T value, params string[] errors) : base(success, type, errors)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public static Result<T> Successful(T value) => new(true, ResultType.SuccessfulWithResult, ValidateValue(value));

    public static Result<T> Created(T value) => new(true, ResultType.Created, ValidateValue(value));

    public static new Result<T> Failed(params string[] errors) => new(false, ResultType.Failed, default, ValidateErrors(errors));

    public static new Result<T> NotFound(params string[] errors) => new(false, ResultType.NotFound, default, ValidateErrors(errors));

    private static T ValidateValue(T value) => value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
}
```

You can make your repository method return a `Task<Result<CustomerProfileDto>>` and in case you have an actual return value you can use a return statement like this one

```cs
return Result<CustomerProfileDto>.Successful(foundCustomerProfileDto);
```

or if you can't find the customer...

```cs
return Result<CustomerProfileDto>.NotFound("Couldn't find the customer"); // Or whatever error message that you want
```

Answer (score 0):

At the first position I think your method is an *async* method, but you didn't use any await in your code so for the first part I think it's a good decision to use await in your code.
For your question, this is based on your contract with your consumer, sometime you can handle that with http status codes, for example a user requested to see a profile that does not exist and somehow it's not for himself so it's better to don't give him any information just return an 403.